# Searching for HTML tag in Phonegap Application

Tags: php, jquery, iphone, cordova

I'm in the middle of writing a phonegap app that contains a database, much like [this](http://pkazz.com/senators/). I want to put a search function in it that, after putting in your search term, scans the html for and id tag and then redirects you to that id. How would I go about doing this? I've done my research and can't find any adequate jQuery or PHP solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you mean any elements whose id's match the search query? Then it's easy.

Comment: How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are just searching for an ID within the DOM?

If using jQuery it would look something like...

```
var search = //However you are doing your search result
var elementId = $('#'+search); //The # means you are searching for an ID. If it was a class you could use a .
```

The above will store the targeted element in the variable "elementId". You can choose what you want to do with it after that.

And if you are using the [ScrollTo jQuery Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) you can do...

```
$.scrollTo(elementId);
```

Which will cause the window to scroll to the element found.

I hope that helps.